# Maximum Size of Stacked BarChart?

Tags: charts

I created some stacked BarCharts in Mathematica 8 and it did work just fine. After opening the file in Mathematica 11, one of the Charts is not "interactive" anymore (no mouse-over, no edges). For each bar there are 10 stacked values. As soon as i eliminate one of the values and reduce the size to 9 stacked values it works just fine again.

Is there a maximum size or an option i have to change to get the "normal" display?

```
BarChart[Transpose[FirstAut[[FAind]]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

These do work:

```
BarChart[Transpose[Drop[FirstAut[[FAind]], 1]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
BarChart[Transpose[Drop[FirstAut[[FAind]], -1]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]

Length[FAind]=10
```

Comment: can you post the code showing this problem?

Comment: PerformanceGoal does not work :-/ but thx anyway